# Trying to select an option in a <select> element using PHP

Tags: php, html

Basically, I have a `<select>` element, with a bunch of options. Let's call them A, B, C, D, E.

I'm trying to do this: without a ton of if statements, I want to have the option for the value of `$var` (which is either A,B,C,D,E) to be shown by default, regardless of its position in the actual select element.

How could I do that?

Comment: I don't think this can be done efficiently without an `if` statement for each option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this way (your options should be in an array)

let

```
$optionList = array ('A','B','C','D','E','F'); 
$var = 'D';
```

then

```
<select name="mySelect">
 <?php foreach($optionList as $k) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $k;?> <?php if($k === $var ) 
       { ?> selected="selected" <?php }// end of if ?> >
     <?php echo $k;?></option>
<?php } // end of foreach  ?>
</select>
```

#### EDIT

or you can use `if(in_array($var,$optionList)) { ? selected ="selected" <?php } ?>`

Comment: I agree with this method but don't see how it handles OP's concern: `without a ton of if statements`. There needs to be an if statement for each option no matter what, maybe I'm misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Wesley he is newbie for that, i also have been suffered this type of problem during my initial days of programming :)

Comment: OK that's what I thought. I once had some fool here suggest to me that the "better" way to do this (to avoid if statements) was to use a DOM parser and inject the attribute :D

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression.